# Group list of words by occurrence / inverse index of strings

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working through [Coding the matrix](http://codingthematrix.com/), though I'm trying to work through it using Haskell rather than Python. One of the exercises has you write a function where you take a list of strings, and then transform them into an inverse index of the words contained in each string, along with the index of the originating string:

```
> makeInverseIndex ["hello world", "world test", "hello test"]
fromList [("hello",fromList [0,2]),("test",fromList [1,2]),("world",fromList [0,1])]
```

You then implement an `orSearch` and an `andSearch`, which returns the indexes of the strings that match the search:

```
> orSearch ["hello", "world"] $ makeInverseIndex ["hello world", "world test", "hello test"]
fromList [0,1,2]

> andSearch ["hello", "world"] $ makeInverseIndex ["hello world", "world test", "hello test"]
fromList [0]
```

Here is my attempt in Haskell:

```
import Data.List as L
import Data.Map.Strict as M
import Data.Set as S

makeInverseIndex :: [String] -> Map String (Set Int)
makeInverseIndex = L.foldr (unionWith S.union . uncurry group) M.empty . zipWithIndex . L.map words
  where
    zipWithIndex :: [a] -> [(Int, a)]
    zipWithIndex xs = zip [0..length xs] xs

    group :: Ord k => v -> [k] -> Map k (Set v)
    group n = M.fromList . L.map (\w -> (w, S.singleton n))

orSearch :: [String] -> Map String (Set Int) -> Set Int
orSearch words =
  M.foldr S.union S.empty . pick words

andSearch :: [String] -> Map String (Set Int) -> Set Int
andSearch words index =
  M.foldr S.intersection (S.fromList [0..length index-1]) . pick words $ index

pick :: Ord k => [k] -> Map k v -> Map k v
pick keys m = 
  restrictKeys m $ S.fromList keys
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Prefer qualified imports for `containers`

The `containers` modules contain several functions that have the same names as their list counterpart. Therefore, they are usually included as *qualified* modules:

```
import           Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import           Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S
```

The types are imported unqualified to make the type signatures easier to read.

Next, it's a easier to exchange your types later if you provide a type synonym:

```
type MultiMap k v = Map k (Set v)
type WordMap      = MultiMap String Int
```

Now, let's have a look at your functions. `zipWithIndex` isn't optimal because it traverses `xs` twice. However the result of `zip` is as long as the shorter of the two lists. We can therefore simply write

```
zipWithIndex xs = zip [0..] xs
```

Note that you don't need a type signature on those local functions. Indeed, they can be misleading, because the `a` in `zipWithIndex` is *not* related to the `a` in the outer function.

## Don't shadow library function names

`group` is a name that's already imported via `Data.List`. Since we now import our containers as qualified, we can simply provide our own `singleton` function to get rid of `group`:

```
singleton :: k -> v -> MultiMap k v
singleton k v = M.singleton k (S.singleton v)
```

Our `makeInverseFunction` would now look like this:

```
singleton :: k -> v -> MultiMap k v
singleton k v = M.singleton k (S.singleton v)

makeInverseIndex :: [String] -> WordMap
makeInverseIndex = foldr (M.unionWith S.union . uncurry insert) M.empty . zipWithIndex . L.map words
  where
    zipWithIndex = zip [0..]

    insert v = foldMap (flip singleton v)
```

## Prefer functions that provide your functionality already

However, there's a function to convert a list of maps into a single map, , [`unionsWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:unionsWith):

```
makeInverseIndex :: [String] -> WordMap
makeInverseIndex = M.unionsWith S.union . concat . zipWith go [0..] . map words
  where
    go index ws = map (flip singleton index) ws
```

I admit that `go` is a bad name in that context. `indexer` might be a better one. By the way, we cannot use `foldMap` or `mconcat` here, since that wouldn't merge the map values.

## Try to relax your type signatures*

`orSearch` is fine, although you could relax its type. Also, `words` is against a function name. You can use `ws` safely in this context.

```
orSearch :: (Ord k, Ord v) => [k] -> MultiMap k v -> Set v
orSearch ws =
  M.foldr S.union S.empty . pick ws
```

<sub>* unless it leads to performance problems or ambiguities</sub>

## Prefer `foldr1` instead of complicated start values

Now, `andSearch` is a little bit tricky. You use `S.fromList [0..length index-1]` in order to have a proper "zero" case. However, if the map is empty, the correct answer should be the empty set, not the complete, right?

So let's handle that case first with `M.null index` and then use `foldr1` from `Map`'s `Foldable` instance:

```
andSearch :: (Ord k, Ord v) => [k] -> MultiMap k v -> Set v
andSearch words index =
  | M.null sets = S.empty
  | otherwise   = foldr1 S.intersection sets
 where
   sets = pick words index
```

Other than that, well done. Keep in mind that there's a `IntSet` in `Data.IntSet` that might be more suitable for your use case.

Comment: Having `andSearch []` return a full set makes `S.intersection (andSearch xs index) (andSearch ys index)` equal to `andSearch (xs ++ ys) index`. Pointlessing `go` into `map . singleton` for inlining might be the lesser evil here.

Comment: @Gurkenglas Pointlessing `go` changes nothing, the resulting core will be the same. There's no [reason to write everything pointfree](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree#Problems_with_pointfree).

Comment: Unfortunately `foldr1` fails if it does not match the keys in `ws`... I've not used `foldr1` before so I'm struggling to work out why: `fromList *** Exception: foldr1: empty structure` (I've included the guard `M.null index = S.empty`)

Comment: Whoops, applied the `M.null` check on the wrong element. `pick` might return `M.empty` even if `index` wasn't empty. You can think of `foldr1 f xs` as `foldr f (last xs) (init xs)` (although it's not implemented that way).